# Android portrait screen orientation doesn't work [React Native]

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I'm working on a react-native app and when I try to set the Android screen orietnation exclusively to portrait, it doesn't work, here's project specs:

```
RNNKotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

And here's my code in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    <application
      tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"

      <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

What's wrong with this code?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this package https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker

It works perfectly and allows you to control orientation from JS side.

```js
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';

...

Orientation.lockToPortrait();

...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I find out the problem was with android version, so I re-created the entire android project up to date and re-installed new deps, and it works now. Developing app for android platform it's a huge mess.

Comment: @PaulRock yep that is why I recommend using library, it hides some complexity inside and gives good API to the developer for both platforms

Comment: Definitely android sucks, I'm using this library.